# Bootstrap collapsed toggler does not load

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've looked at dozens of posts about this kind of issue and haven't been able to find the answer. I am having an issue with my navbar menu toggle on collapse. When the browser width is smaller, the menu button shows, but clicking on the menu button does nothing. I need it to display the menu list, obviously. Here's the code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm bg-faded navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a id="header-initials" class="navbar-brand" href="home">JT</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">skills</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">about</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#work">work</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Attach **jquery.js** and **bootstrap.js** before `</body>`  tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` after the `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

I've tested the above changes. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you added the bootstrap.min.js to your code?
if not
add this code after jQuery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to need call `bootstrap.js` before closing `</body>` tag along with other JavaScript file. Example here

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm bg-faded navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a id="header-initials" class="navbar-brand" href="home">JT</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">skills</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">about</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#work">work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```